# how to remove seal When I sign many times

Tags: itext7

How I sign pdf by p12:

```
signer.setFieldName(fieldName);
signer.signDetached(digest, pks, chain, null, null, null, 0, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS);
```

How I try to remove one sign:

```
PdfAcroForm.removeField(fieldName);
PdfAcroForm.flattenFields();
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to know? You have code for removing a form field but you don't explain what your problem is with your code...

Comment: The code is found from the document.https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/examples/itext-7/remove-digital-signatures .but , all sign is remove . Actually I only want to remove the one by fieldName .Or  remove the latest

Comment: Removing the latest signature(s)  might be achieved. Do you want to remove the whole field or only the signature value and the visualization thereof? And have you applied other changes (e.g. form fill-ins) in the same revision or afterwards which you want to keep? (I ask because only certain operations are allowed on a signed pdf, and removing form fields is not among them, so one has to improvise a bit...)

Comment: if can,i want to remove the signature value and the visualization thereo by fieldName . can you help me

Comment: I'll try and write something up later this week.

Comment: It took me longer that that week, I hope it still helps.

Answer (score 1):

*If one looks for an example for removing digital signatures on the iText site, one finds [this example](https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/examples/itext-7/remove-digital-signatures) (as you did). This is a bit misleading as it strictly speaking is an example for **flattening** a signature, i.e. removing the whole signature field but making its visual appearance part of the page content. Actually the code is flattening not only the signature field but all fields.*

*You clarified in a comment to your question, though:*

> *i want to remove the signature value and the visualization thereo by fieldName*

*So you in particular want to change only the signature field, you don't want to actually remove it but merely clear it, and you don't want to keep its appearance. Thus, the example you found does not match your requirements in multiple ways.*

First of all, you can only clear the most recently signed signature field(s); otherwise you invalidate any more recent signatures. So we can assume that the signature field you want to clear is the outermost one.

To clear the signature field as you want to, you need to remove its value (the actual signature and some metadata) and the appearances of the field widgets (strictly speaking ISO 32000-2 allows only a single widget but there are a number of PDFs in the wild with signature fields with multiple visualizations), e.g. using this method:

```java
String clearLastSignature(PdfDocument pdfDocument) {
    SignatureUtil signatureUtil = new SignatureUtil(pdfDocument);
    PdfAcroForm acroForm = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdfDocument, false);

    List<String> signatureNames = signatureUtil.getSignatureNames();
    if (signatureNames != null && signatureNames.size() > 0) {
        String lastSignatureName = signatureNames.get(signatureNames.size() - 1);
        PdfFormField lastSignatureField = acroForm.getField(lastSignatureName);
        if (null != lastSignatureField.getPdfObject().remove(PdfName.V))
            lastSignatureField.getPdfObject().setModified();
        for (PdfWidgetAnnotation pdfWidgetAnnotation : lastSignatureField.getWidgets()) {
            if (pdfWidgetAnnotation.getPdfObject().remove(PdfName.AP) != null)
                pdfWidgetAnnotation.getPdfObject().setModified();
        }
        return lastSignatureName;
    }
    return null;
}
```

*(from [ClearSignature.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext7/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext7/signature/ClearSignature.java#L132))*

This method additionally returns the name of the cleared field which can be helpful if you want to resign it soon after.

You can use this method like this:

```java
try (   PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(source);
        PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(clearedFile);
        PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfReader, pdfWriter, new StampingProperties().useAppendMode())) {
    String clearedSignatureName = clearLastSignature(pdfDocument);
}
```

*([ClearSignature](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext7/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext7/signature/ClearSignature.java#L78) test `testClearLastSignatureIncrementally`)*

Applied to the output  "step6_signed_by_alice_bob_carol_and_dave.pdf" of the iText signature whitepaper example `C2_11_SignatureWorkflow`

[image: screen shot original]

you get

[image: screen shot cleared]

and after resigning the signature field you get this

[image: screen shot resigned]

Beware: Depending on PDF permissions and restrictions this may fail for some PDF documents.